# Neo4j 3.0.0 + SPATIAL in Cypher

Tags: neo4j, cypher, neo4j-spatial

I've compiled the latest `Neo4j Spatial` `(neo4j-spatial-0.16-neo4j-3.0.0-server-plugin.jar)` from source and dropped it into my `Neo4j 3.0.0` plugins folder.

The extension is listed in the browser, and I can do `POST` calls for spatial functionality.

However, I believe I should also be able to use the nifty new `CALL` feature in `Neo4j 3.0.0` to make `Cypher` calls, like this:

```
CALL spatial.addPointLayer('cities');
```

As alluded to by Stefan's update here:

[How do I create a spacial index in neo4j using only cypher?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26560023/how-do-i-create-a-spacial-index-in-neo4j-using-only-cypher)

And shown here:

http://jexp.github.io/graphgist/idx?dropbox-14493611%2Fcypher_spatial.adoc

However, I get a "There is no procedure with the name `spatial.addPointLayer` registered for this database instance." error, and can see the same calls failing in the jexp example as well... I'm not sure if I'm just too early to the party or missing something?

Comment: Did you find a solution to this question? I am able to get the list of procedures using "CALL spatial.procedures()", or a list of layers when using "CALL spatial.laterTypes()" but when trying to call any of the returned procedures, or the documented procedures, I receive "Failed to invoke procedure `spatial.layers`: Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/geotools/filter/text/cql2/CQLException"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The plugin needs to be in the database-specific Plugin folder and not in the "Neo4j CE 3.0.x/Plugins" folder.

Answer (score 0):

In Neo4j 3.0, for basic operations you don't need the spatial plugin.

There is default support for `point` and `distance`. This support assumes you will set lat/lon property keys as `latitude` and `longitude`.

You can the use them for calculating distance between two nodes, for example :

```
MATCH (a:City {name:'London'}), (b:City {name:'Barcelona'})
RETURN distance(point(a), point(b))/1000 as dist
```

You can find a detailed example in this graphgist :

http://gist.asciidoctor.org/?dropbox-14493611%2Fcypher_spatial.adoc#_spatial_procedures

Secondly, in Neo4j 3.0 appears stored procedures, an official set of procedures is supported by neo4j here :

https://github.com/neo4j-contrib/neo4j-apoc-procedures

Which provides some more spatial features.

Comment: Thanks Christophe, I should clarify that I would like to try a spatial index. The default spatial capabilities in Neo4j 3.0 appear to be slow, so I was hoping to use Neo4j-spatial to implement an index and attempting to do so via Cypher.

Comment: Ha ok, I think Craig Taverner is working on that side, I'll ask  him